# Boolean toggle for class method

Tags: javascript

I know there are similar questions but they do not provide the answer I am looking for. So what I'm trying to do is create a method that will toggle a boolean value.

```js
class Example {
   constructor(name) {
     this._name = name;
     this._booleanExample = true;
  }
  toggleBoolean() {
    this._booleanExample = !this._booleanExample;
  }
}
```

I must not be doing something right though because when I call this method it does not toggle the boolean value.

```js
const exampleOne = new Example('example');
exampleOne.toggleBoolean();
// the output remains true
```

**Update**:

Ok, so it must be something wrong with the site that I am using because I just recreated the example code inside VSC and everything works fine. I can assess and retrieve the booleanExample and also toggle it from true to false and vice versa.

Comment: Looks ok, how are you checking the value of `_booleanExample`?

Comment: yeah, code looks fine. Try to access the ```_booleanExample``` as ```exampleOne._booleanExample``` You will get the value then.

Comment: I'm checking the value with a simple:
`console.log(exampleOne)`
because I also have a getter in my code but I cannot seem to get a non 'undefined' return.

Comment: You should be able to delete the question yourself if you want. Not sure what you're getting at about which site you're using and slander??

Comment: Uhm..well if I said that the IDE provided during the lessons is garbage would that not be slander?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do this, but you could try using an arrow function for `toggleBoolean` to ensure that it's using the class-level `this` context.

```
class Example {
   constructor(name) {
     this._name = name;
     this._booleanExample = true;
  }
  toggleBoolean = () => {
    this._booleanExample = !this._booleanExample;
  }
}
```

Comment: This change isn't needed, the error from OP is not reproducable (as they've acknowledged)